# How to remove Visual Studio formatting after "("

Tags: visual-studio, c#

I really hate formatting in my editors. I've got most of the formatting gone from Visual Studio but there is one I can't find out how to change it. Here's what is happening:

C#, Unity.

I type:

```
void Update(){
```

And it corrects to:

```
void Update() { }
```

I want there to be no formatting so that the `}` does not appear and there is no space inserted between `)` and `{`.

I've tried turning off most of the stuff under Tools/Options/C# but I must be missing one.

Comment: This cannot be done { and } is required for the code to compiled.  This isn’t the case of optional brackets for a one line of statement

Comment: @Ramhound I know the code cannot be compiled without both brackets. I just don't want the EDITOR to put the second bracket and the space there. Is that not possible?

Comment: I would look for an add-on to accomplish that behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound will do. Though does it change anything if I only talk about the space added before the bracket?

Comment: No; It actually doesn’t

Answer (score 0):

This option is called "Automatic brace completion" and is found in:

C# only:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General > Automatic brace completion

All languages:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General > Automatic brace completion

This will disable the option for all brackets : `{ ( [ " ' /*`.

Comment: I swear I've  turned that off, I'll double check when I get home.

Comment: It is turned off and does not solve my problem :(

Comment: That's very surprising if turning this off doesn't help. It might be worth a bug report to Microsoft.